# Arc-length of $y = \sin(x^2)$ from $x = 0$ to $x = \sqrt\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the arc-length of $y = \sin(x^2)$ between $x=0$ and $x = \sqrt{\pi}$

I got all the way to $L = \int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos^2(x^2)}dx$ where L = arc length, but did not integrate correctly. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The derivative of $\sin(x^2)$ is $2x\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: There is no good reason to think that $\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{1+4x^2\cos^2(x^2)}\,dx$ has a nice closed form. One can, however, approximate the integral numerically.

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that even the arc length of the simpler function $\sin x$ does not possess a so-called closed form (it can be expressed in terms of [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), but that's merely a rewriting), so it would be absurd to expect an even more complex expression to possess one. Indeed, the integral in question can also be rewritten in terms of another special function, namely the [Fresnel *S* integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), but that's about it.